# amavisd Net server pid file already exists after system crash and startup

Tags: centos, amavis

whenever i have an unclean shutdown, which is often due to power failure most of the time i get problems with amavis starting up.

The error amavisd Net server pid_file already exists for running process comes when i start it under debug mode, so i always have to delete the amavisd.pid and amavisd.lock
files manually before it starts.

Is there a way i can stop this from happening or get a way to delete the files during reboot in the case of an unclean shutdown.

I am running the latest version of amavisd-new 2.6.4 on a centos 5.4 server

Thanks

Comment: If it happens often enough to be a problem, you might look into getting a good UPS and cable it to the server so it can do a clean shutdown if power is going to cut out. Otherwise you risk having a damaged filesystem so nothing will start...

Comment: I am working on that too.

Answer (score 1):

One not very smart way to handle this problem is to add a line in your initd startup script that deletes the file in question at startup.

Make sure you put it somewhere before amavisd starts.

Comment: I would put anyway a little check to see if no other amavis instances are running and then delete the pid file

Comment: Even better ! :)